# .Net Form Layout - create Chat UI like facebook or google hangouts

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms, layout, chat

I want to create an application and chatting is involved. I am currently struggling to format existing controls or to create a control with the following conditions:

- a container is docked to the main form's bottom
- inside of that container, a button can be used to toggle a chat
  component (e.g. text edit) to become either visible or invisible
- if visible, the chat component is aligned with the button that was
  pressed but does not force a resize on the container of the button

So basically I want to achieve a facebook or google hangouts like chat layout in vb.net that can also scale dynamically according to the current window size. Nevertheless it should always stick to the bottom.

Please keep in mind that this question is not about making the chat work but only the layout/design problem I am facing.

My current approach is the following:

- FlowLayoutPanel docked to bottom with buttons
- RichEdit as placeholders to simulate the chat component

[My current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClOvb.jpg)

Is there an easier way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Set the anchors to the bottom of the page/panel.

On the designer, click the control you want to edit, find the `Anchor` property and change it to bottom (and left/right/top, whatever you'd like).

Comment: If I change the Anchor property, the buttons get aligned as I want, but that does not solve the problem I am facing when I try to show a chat window (TextBox in my image). I have to find a way to align the chat window with the button while the FlowLayoutPanel does not resize.

Comment: YourTextBox.Visible = False/True based off of the button click. If you want your FlowLayoutPanel to resize with the form, then anchor it as well.